# How to delete current class using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple div's,I want to remove the class named "inactive" that I have click on.I tried lot but couldn't find any solution.My html div's code are given below :

```
<ul class="job-tile">
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock1'></div></li>
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock1'></div></li>
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock1'></div></li>
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock1'></div></li>
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock1'></div></li>
  </ul>
```

And my js code is something like below :

```
 $('ul li').click(function() 
        {

        if ($(".clock1")){
          $(this).closest('clock1').removeClass('inactive');
        }
    });
```

I am stuck in there.Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: First thing... remove the duplicate `ids`. `id` is unique.

Comment: Why do you have an `if()` statement? Why not just `$(this).find(".inactive").removeClass("inactive")`?

Comment: Your selector inside the if() statement seems off. Shouldn't it be $(this).closest(".clock1").removeClass...

Comment: Also, that if() statement will always return true, even if there are no elements with class "clock1".  The correct statement would be if($(".clock1").length)

Comment: And FYI, your example HTML is invalid. The `div` elements require a closing tag `</div>`. Posting invalid markup makes it a little confusing. ;-)

Comment: Ok,I will try with this,but i mean i want to remove inactive class from current li.cookie monster

Comment: This code is working but see in my html code,here I am using five li.when I click first li than inactive class have to remove but when i click second li,I need to add class inactive in first li,remove inactive class from second li.What to do @ cookie monster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

First `Don't use same id's for different element` and correct HTML `add closing div tag`:

```
<ul class="job-tile">
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock1'></div></li>
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock2'></div></li>
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock3'></div></li>
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock4'></div></li>
    <li><div class="clock1 inactive" id='clock5'></div></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$('ul li').click(function() 
 {        
   if ($(this).find('div').hasClass('clock1')){
       $(this).find('div.clock1').removeClass('inactive');
   }
 });
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmzYB/2/)

**Updated:**

You can use [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```
$('ul li').click(function() 
 {        
     if ($(this).find('div').hasClass('clock1')){   
        $(this).find('div.clock1').removeClass('inactive');
        $(this).prevAll().find('div.clock1').addClass('inactive');//-- All previous li's
        $(this).nextAll().find('div.clock1').addClass('inactive');//-- All next li's
     }
 });
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mmzYB/3/)

Comment: Yes,its working fine,but see this html,if I clicked in first li class inactive is removed.But when I clicked in second,third li,it also remove same class but add another class in first clicked li.How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$( 'ul li' ).click( function() {
    $( this ).find( '.clock1' ).removeClass( 'inactive' );
});
```

Comment: you mean $(this) ? nvm, you fixed it as I was commenting

Comment: u found that the author is using same id for many li's??? more over $(this) should be like $('this')??? updated as i was commenting :D

Comment: @GreenWizard yes, but this will be not a problem in this case. Anyway MikeSmithDev already mentioned this in comments

Comment: This code is working but see in my html code,here I am using five li.when I click first li than inactive class will remove but when I click second li,I need to add class inactive in first li an than remove inactive class from second li.What to do? @antyrat

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.job-tile > li > div').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('inactive')){
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');
  }
});
```

Comment: By moving the handler to the `div`, you're likely changing the desired behavior. And `.remove()` isn't what is wanted. You're removing the entire element.